# Synchronise structure of multiple database

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have 2 database:

production and to test.

Production should have the same fields and tables like testdatabase.

is there any software, or script to show difference between this two databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [DBComparer](http://dbcomparer.com/) and it's free :). A google search for `database compare tools` should yield other useful links.

I also used [SQL Delta](http://www.sqldelta.com/) one time. It is a fantastic tool with many advanced features but it is not free. You can however download a trial from their website.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Redgate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=sqlcompare&gclid=CKXjrp2H_6ECFVls4wod0yYiEw). It's not free but works really nicely and is really easy to use.